# FQL like table returning undocumented object types

Tags: facebook, web-applications, facebook-fql

Hey I'm playing around with the FQL api for a facebook app idea I have and it seems that the like table is not returning the documented object types, here is an output of my likes

```
SELECT object_id, post_id, object_type FROM like WHERE user_id = me()

{
  "data": [
    {
      "object_id": "10151258431583394",
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "profile"
    },
    {
      "object_id": 478582878859930,
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "list"
    },
    {
      "object_id": 521644514513038,
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "list"
    },
    {
      "object_id": 106925839472986,
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "profile"
    },
    {
      "object_id": "10101021654513450",
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "profile"
    },
    {
      "object_id": "10101017009447200",
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "photo"
    },
    {
      "object_id": "10151245338443394",
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "profile"
    },
    {
      "object_id": 162988417181213,
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "list"
    },
    {
      "object_id": 439293976134330,
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "list"
    },
    {
      "object_id": 440364829332399,
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "profile"
    },
    {
      "object_id": "10151229280723394",
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "profile"
    },
    {
      "object_id": 489203737786963,
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "list"
    },
    {
      "object_id": "10152125564767619",
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "profile"
    },
    {
      "object_id": "10151113526476775",
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "profile"
    },
    {
      "object_id": "10151113525441775",
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "profile"
    },
    {
      "object_id": "10151113524916775",
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "profile"
    },
    {
      "object_id": "10151113523716775",
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "profile"
    },
    {
      "object_id": 123390361144776,
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "list"
    },
    {
      "object_id": "10151199315428394",
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "profile"
    },
    {
      "object_id": 278542695598345,
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "list"
    },
    {
      "object_id": 425466477503260,
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "profile"
    },
    {
      "object_id": 531362840223562,
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "profile"
    },
    {
      "object_id": 531362946890218,
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "profile"
    },
    {
      "object_id": 517081921654425,
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "list"
    },
    {
      "object_id": "10151184643108394",
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "profile"
    },
    {
      "object_id": 285512984897612,
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "profile"
    },
    {
      "object_id": 284572424991668,
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "profile"
    },
    {
      "object_id": "10152126582670161",
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "profile"
    },
    {
      "object_id": "10151172644678394",
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "profile"
    },
    {
      "object_id": "10100959925933020",
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "profile"
    },
    {
      "object_id": 170144483122267,
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "list"
    },
    {
      "object_id": "10152100222280161",
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "profile"
    },
    {
      "object_id": 335741896516584,
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "profile"
    },
    {
      "object_id": "10151216733207457",
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "profile"
    },
    {
      "object_id": "10150966158886775",
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "profile"
    },
    {
      "object_id": 357351974342058,
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "list"
    },
    {
      "object_id": "10152073370825161",
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "profile"
    },
    {
      "object_id": 337226756372190,
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "list"
    },
    {
      "object_id": "10151044156886775",
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "profile"
    },
    {
      "object_id": 122273294554916,
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "profile"
    },
    {
      "object_id": "10152061553435161",
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "profile"
    },
    {
      "object_id": "10151149031423896",
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "profile"
    },
    {
      "object_id": "10152074656495188",
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "profile"
    },
    {
      "object_id": 335744249849682,
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "profile"
    },
    {
      "object_id": 335744153183025,
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "profile"
    },
    {
      "object_id": 335743509849756,
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "profile"
    },
    {
      "object_id": 335743463183094,
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "profile"
    },
    {
      "object_id": 335743403183100,
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "profile"
    },
    {
      "object_id": 335743376516436,
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "profile"
    },
    {
      "object_id": 335743259849781,
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "profile"
    },
    {
      "object_id": 335743139849793,
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "profile"
    },
    {
      "object_id": 335742603183180,
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "profile"
    },
    {
      "object_id": 335742569849850,
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "profile"
    },
    {
      "object_id": 335742419849865,
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "profile"
    },
    {
      "object_id": 335742323183208,
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "profile"
    },
    {
      "object_id": 335742226516551,
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "profile"
    },
    {
      "object_id": 335742213183219,
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "profile"
    },
    {
      "object_id": 335742169849890,
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "profile"
    },
    {
      "object_id": 335742033183237,
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "profile"
    },
    {
      "object_id": "10101326761860672",
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "profile"
    },
    {
      "object_id": "10151035255316775",
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "profile"
    },
    {
      "object_id": "10152047005670511",
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "photo"
    },
    {
      "object_id": "10151194367147619",
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "profile"
    },
    {
      "object_id": "10151111702663394",
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "photo"
    },
    {
      "object_id": 732497948354,
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "photo"
    },
    {
      "object_id": "10152002641675161",
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "profile"
    },
    {
      "object_id": 390781734321391,
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "profile"
    },
    {
      "object_id": "10151012309836775",
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "profile"
    },
    {
      "object_id": "10151185665687317",
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "photo"
    },
    {
      "object_id": "10152014894905188",
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "profile"
    },
    {
      "object_id": "10151161548307619",
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "profile"
    },
    {
      "object_id": "10151161549777619",
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "profile"
    },
    {
      "object_id": "10151161552387619",
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "profile"
    },
    {
      "object_id": "10151118986026775",
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "profile"
    },
    {
      "object_id": 191434787659630,
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "profile"
    },
    {
      "object_id": "10151003723472163",
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "profile"
    },
    {
      "object_id": "10100932691640760",
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "profile"
    },
    {
      "object_id": "10100253964691241",
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "profile"
    },
    {
      "object_id": "10100253951333011",
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "profile"
    },
    {
      "object_id": "10151163103492619",
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "profile"
    },
    {
      "object_id": "10151161573682619",
      "post_id": "",
      "object_type": "profile"
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see most of the object types are profile or list, and when querying most of the profile object types I get a "Unsupported get request." exception.

How can I retrieve more information about these objects? Why are there no photo, album, event, group, note, link, video, application, status, check-in, review, comment, post types?

It seems that this is not working as intended or the functionality has changed but the documentation has not been updated.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of ways.

You could issue follow-on queries to get more info about each liked object.  For example:

```
select src_big from photo where object_id="10151287927181749"
```

**However**, I prefer using Graph API and its "Field Expansion" to follow connections and fetch data about connected objects in one query. For example:

https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=likes.fields(link,likes,cover)

https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID?fields=likes.fields(link,likes,cover)

[Demo using the Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Dlikes.fields%28link%2Clikes%2Ccover%29)

This query gets all the likes for the current user **and** returns the link, like count, and cover image url *for each liked object*.

See the Field Expansion doc to build queries that follow connections and return fields of connected objects:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/field_expansion/